# New Strands of Research

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What is the meaning of the phrase "new strands of research" in the following sentence:

> The last two decades have also seen the emergence of ***new strands of
>   research*** on multilingualism which have incorporated critical and
>   poststructuralist perspective from social theory and embraced new
>   epistemologies and research methods.

Is there any synonym for this phrase or for the word *strand* in this context?

Comment: It's probably a natural off-shoot of the phrase "line of research", with the added caveat that "strand" perhaps indicates that the subject is less heavily researched.

Comment: See also _thread of the argument, skein of discourse, weaving a story,_ etc. The metaphor theme `Writing` Is `Weaving` is very old and dates to the invention of writing, which was described in terms of weaving, a previously invented technology, rather the same way we talk about computing using office metaphors like _file_. This theme is echoed in the [etymology of the PIE root *teks-](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/LanguageFossils.pdf), the source of both _text_ and _textile_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the definitions of *[strand](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/strand#strand-2)* denotes this metaphoric application:

> 1.3 An element that forms part of a complex whole:
>
> *ODO*

The research is the *complex whole*, and the strands are *elements* of that research.

The [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=strand&allowed_in_frame=0) makes the analogous word picture clear:

> "***individual fiber of a rope***, string, etc.," late 15c.,   probably from
>   a continental Germanic source akin to Old High German *streno* "*lock*,
>   *tress*, *strand of hair*,"
>   Middle Dutch *strene* "*a skein*, *hank of thread*,"
>   German *Strähne* "*a skein*, *strand*," of unknown connection.
>   Perhaps to
>   English via an Old French form.
>
> *Etymonline.com*